# Orientdb does not use index when order by is used

Tags: indexing, sql-order-by, orientdb

I have Class `Comapny` with property `name`. On this property I have a `FULLTEXT SBTREE` index. I use fulltext index for searching substrings in company name `select from Company where name containstext 'foo' order by name`
When I execute query with order by `select from Company order by name limit 25` the query does not use this index.
Am I using wrong type of index ?
Thank you.

```
info property company.name

PROPERTY 'Company.name'

Type.................: STRING
Mandatory............: true
Not null.............: true
Read only............: false
Default value........: null
Minimum value........: null
Maximum value........: null
REGEXP...............: null
Collate..............: {OCaseInsensitiveCollate : name = ci}
Linked class.........: null
Linked type..........: null

INDEXES (1 altogether)
+----+------------+----------+
|#   |NAME        |PROPERTIES|
+----+------------+----------+
|0   |Company.name|[name]    |
+----+------------+----------+


INDEXES
+----+------------------+--------------------+-------+---------+-------+-----------------+
|#   |NAME              |TYPE                |RECORDS|CLASS    |COLLATE|FIELDS           |
+----+------------------+--------------------+-------+---------+-------+-----------------+
|2   |Company.name      |FULLTEXT            |17648  |Company  |ci     |name(STRING)     |


explain select from Company order by name limit 25

{
  "@type": "d",
  "@version": 0,
  "fullySortedByIndex": false,
  "documentReads": 8447,
  "current": "#80:2119",
  "documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass": 8447,
  "recordReads": 8447,
  "fetchingFromTargetElapsed": 49,
  "indexIsUsedInOrderBy": false,
  "orderByElapsed": 48,
  "evaluated": 8447,
  "user": "#5:3",
  "elapsed": 97.22936,
  "resultType": "collection",
  "resultSize": 25,
  "@fieldTypes": "documentReads=l,current=x,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass=l,recordReads=l,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,orderByElapsed=l,evaluated=l,user=x,elapsed=f"
}
```

Comment: Hi, which version are you using? Thx

Comment: @michela-bonizzi v2.2.17